# Link 'to' instead of 'href' in react nav dropdown

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a dropdown in Navigation bar and I want react to use `<Link to='/login'>` like feature in dropdown menu. Currently I have
`<NavDropdown.Item href='/somewhere'>Link</NavDropdown.Item>`

which reloads the page everytime click on the link. How can I achieve `Link` feature in dropdown

Comment: which ui library are you using?

Comment: I am using react-bootstrap

Comment: An attempt should be to wrap <NavDropdown> with <Link> or vice versa.  The url must be in <Link> tag.

Comment: I tried but wrapping `Link` inside `NavDropdown.Item` but it works only if particular text is clicked, not the dropdown div and vice-versa wrapping one another is not working

Comment: There's another way: don't do linking with link element, but do it programmatically.

Comment: I got around it with vanilla bootstrap and putting Link inside the list